# Combinatorics on seats and circular tables

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to arrange 6 people around a circular table with 7 seats? (Two seatings are considered the same if one is a rotation of the other.)?

I know that if it was just 6 seats it would be $\frac{6!}{6}$ but with 7 seats??? I'm not too sure about this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty seat 'fixes' the arrangement and so you simply have $6!$ possibilities.

**An alternative answer**

Let the invisible man join the dinner party. Then there are $\frac{7!}{7}$ possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply consider the emty seat as the $7-th$ person which is seating at the table, so the answer is $\frac{7!}{7}=6!$

Note:You can do this because there is one only emty seat.If there would be two,or more, this trick won't work anymore,because then,you would have more persons that are identical.

Lets solve,for example,if there are 6 people and 10 seats.
The first person  has to choose between all 10 seats.The second one,gets to choose between the remaining 9 seats so the answer is $\frac{10*9*8*7*6*5}{10}$.
It is divided by 10 because we count every seating 10 times, because if one seating is obtained from the rotation of other,it is considered the same and we can rotate a seating in 10 total ways